# What is MaxJSONlength good for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

So I recently had a problem in my MVC project. When asking for a JSON response, all I got was an empty string. Setting the MaxJSONlength to a bigger value solved this problem, but I'm a bit unsure as to what it's good for? Is it to protect your server/clients from sending/receiving too much data? Is it Because the serializer needs to know how large an object might be? Neither google nor MSDN had the answers for these questions.

It feels a bit... strange to me to limit an object's size, but I'm probably gravely mistaken in that thought.

I hope someone can clear this up for me,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 4MB of Unicode string [default limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx) that was defined for the JavaScriptSerializer. JSON is a wire format and sending large datasets over networks might hurt the performance of the application. So this limit is like an alarm that you can turn off in the morning and continue sleeping but there is a risk you will be late for work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Although I would've expected the thing to just go "limitless" if not set.