# Is MaxJsonLength safe to always set to max value?

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a controller that returns a `json` that populates the grid in my view. Depending on the filters, the user can retrieve large amount of data in one call so I set the MaxJsonLength to **max**:

```
var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
```

My question is, is it safe to always set the `MaxJsonLength`  to max value? What are its draw-backs?(if there is any)

I found this related post but it didn't answered my question.

[What is MaxJSONlength good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988445/what-is-maxjsonlength-good-for)

I need your expertise here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is good idea to set it to `MaxValue` on each call. It does not mean it will break your application, but it may make your application appear broken.
I've had the same problem once - in some sittuations user might have requested bigger dataset. Like 10-50 megabytes large, through internet connection, not LAN. Nothing impossible, you can send such data sets. But your application will be dead-slow. Browser will be waiting for the data, users will wait long time before page will be usable, which in turn causes them to do silly stuff like clicking everywhere, cursing and reporting bugs in application. Is it really bug? Depends on your requirements, but I would say yes.

What you can and should do is to provide pagination. Send small sets of data to users, display them immediately, allow users to work with them and then send additional data as needed. Or if it always be needed - send it automatically in packages in background, but in smaller sets, that will be quickly dispalyed. Users will get their page ready quickly and most of the time they won't notice that not all data is already there - by the time they will need it it will be already downloaded.
With today's supprot for `AJAX`, `jQuery` and stuff like that doing it should not be any more difficult than it is to get and display whole data set at once.

Comment: Thanks Pako! But problem is, my grid columns are customizable. Meaning, the user can add any related columns to the grid. Say he adds all 30 columns in the grid and retrieves 20 records per page. The data traffic will still be heavy eventhough he just retrieved small amount of records.

Comment: Yes, but depending on your data in htose columns - 20 records x 30 columns is still a lot less than 200 records x 30 columns. There is no perfect answer on how to handle such cases, but paging is what you should be looking for. Also you may create some variants with loading columns on demand, or loading data for bigger (like long text) columns in separate request so that initial data is available quickly, and long data a second or two later (don't forget to put a spinner or omething there)

Comment: Going back, so you're saying that there's no problem if I set the MaxJsonLength to max except it'll 'look' broken? But performance-wise, it wont be a problem as long as I dont reach that max limit?

Comment: There is no problem since it's going to work. You can even set it in web.config file and that's fine. But you simply need to know that it is far from being good solution to a problem and if you're trying to create good application you need to look for better solutions. Also - code not being broken does not mean that application is correct from user's perspective. And performance will be an issue - bigger JSON you will try to send, longer it will take - which might be an issue.